# Django converting year to a full date

Tags: python, django, date

In my book aplication I have a date field in model, but as an input from REST request sometimes I am getting just a year, or even full date but as a string format. I wanted to create at first a manual form to add a books where i don't know exact date of publication despite a year.

So what I am trying to do is in case of getting just a year add "01/01" and convert is to a date with 
".strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d").date()".  But that's not working, datefield default validator is preventing me from passing anything else than "yyyy-mm-dd" format input. Can i somehow overwrite a default validaotr or stop launching it by a form ? Any suggestion how to handle that problem?

Models:

```
class Book(models.Model):

title = models.CharField(max_length=100)           
publication_date = models.DateField()   
authors = models.ManyToManyField("Author", related_name="author")
ISBN = ISBNField() #validators=[book_unique_validator,]
pages = models.IntegerField(validators=[page_validator,], blank=True)
language = models.CharField(max_length=4)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

views:

```
class BookAddView(FormView):
    model = Book
    template_name = "Books/create_book.html"    
    form_class = BookForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("book_list")

    def form_valid(self, form):    
        if Book.objects.filter(ISBN=form.cleaned_data["ISBN"]).count() > 0:
            messages.warning(self.request, f'Book "{form.cleaned_data["ISBN"]}" already exist in database.')
            return redirect("book_details", pk=Book.objects.get(ISBN=form.cleaned_data["ISBN"]).pk)
        else:
            if len(publication_date=form.cleaned_data['publication_date']) == 4:
                book_date = (form.cleaned_data['publication_date'] + "01/01").strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
            else:
                book_date = publication_date=form.cleaned_data['publication_date']
        new_book = Book(
                    title=form.cleaned_data["title"].lower(),                    
                    publication_date=book_date,
                    ISBN=form.cleaned_data["ISBN"],
                    pages=form.cleaned_data["pages"],
                    language=form.cleaned_data["language"]
                )
            authors = Author.objects.filter(pk__in=form.cleaned_data["authors"])
            new_book.save()
            for author in authors:
                new_book.authors.add(author)
            new_book.save()
            pk = new_book.pk
            return redirect("covers_add", pk=pk)
```

forms:

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField()
    publication_date = forms.CharField()
    authors = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Author.objects.all())
    ISBN = ISBNField()
    pages = forms.IntegerField()
    language = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ["title", "publication_date", "authors", "ISBN", "pages", "language"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `year`, `month` and `day` to `datetime.datetime` class when only year is provided.

```
import datetime

if len(publication_date=form.cleaned_data['publication_date']) == 4:
    book_date = datetime.datetime(int(form.cleaned_data['publication_date']), month=1, day=1).date()
```

`datetime.datetime(int(form.cleaned_data['publication_date']), month=1, day=1)` will return a `datetime.datetime` object. So you can easily get the `date()` from that.

Further read [datetime Objects](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)

Comment: But still DateField() validator is preventing me from passing just a year as an input value for a date. Can I turn it off somehow?

Comment: I am not getting what you mentioned. which validator you are referring to? In your code I don't see any validator. please explain

Comment: In my models I have DateField() and in forms.ModelForm I have passed the same name of parameter with another field == CharField and when I am typing there "1992" for example I'm getting an error "please insert a correct date format YYYY-MM-DD".

Comment: thats what this code will do, `datetime.datetime(int(form.cleaned_data['publication_date']), month=1, day=1).date()` will return a datetime object. You can pass this to `str()` and it will return a string in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. I think I am still missing something.